# Return ArrayList item instead of boolean

Tags: java

In the following code, I define a method called `loadItems`, that it's supposed of creating an array list of type `Item` with each line of a text file.

- The Item object is formed by a String that contains a name, and an int variable with a number.
- Each line of the text file contains a name to store in a new item, followed by `=` and before that, the number that needs to be stored in the new item. Summarizing, each line looks something like: `String=int`.

The problem is that, instead of returning a new item and store it in the `loadItems` Array List, I get an error because it's supposed to return a boolean. I image this is caused because the new Item is created inside a while function that checks for a new line in the text file.

```java
    ArrayList<Item> loadItems() throws FileNotFoundException {

        File phaseOneFile = new File("Phase-1.txt");
        Scanner readPhaseOneFile = new Scanner(phaseOneFile);

        while (readPhaseOneFile.hasNextLine()){
            String actualLine = readPhaseOneFile.nextLine();
            String[] actualLineToItem = actualLine.split("=");

            Item newItem = new Item();
            newItem.itemName=actualLineToItem[0];
            newItem.itemWeight= Integer.parseInt(actualLineToItem[1]);

            return loadItems().add(newItem);

        } 

    }
```

Comment: Don't return inside your loop as this will stop it in the first iteration making it useless. Return the list after the loop has run and added everything. Edit: Also don't call a method in itself without really knowing what you are doing. Even without the current error your loadItems method would keep on calling itself until the end of the universe (or until you kill the program running it). There is absolutly no need for recursion in your code.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS to be fair, the stack would blow up a lot earlier than the end of the universe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things.

- You return too early
- You return the wrong thing
- You use recursion for no discernible reason

First, you should return just *after* you have built your list, so remove the `return`.

Second, return the list after the loop ends

Third, accumulate stuff inside an actual `ArrayList` and return that instead of recursing.

Fourth, no need to return a concrete type, just return a `List<Item>`.

```
List<Item> loadItems() throws FileNotFoundException {

    File phaseOneFile = new File("Phase-1.txt");
    Scanner readPhaseOneFile = new Scanner(phaseOneFile);
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    while (readPhaseOneFile.hasNextLine()){
        String actualLine = readPhaseOneFile.nextLine();
        String[] actualLineToItem = actualLine.split("=");

        Item newItem = new Item();
        newItem.itemName=actualLineToItem[0];
        newItem.itemWeight= Integer.parseInt(actualLineToItem[1]);

        items.add(newItem);

    } 

    return items;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are returning `loadItems().add(newItem);`. From the Javadocs for `Collection#add()` (which `ArrayList` implements):

> Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-

Obviously `true` is of type `boolean`. However, in your method signiture (`ArrayList<Item> loadItems() throws FileNotFoundException`), you state that your method returns `ArrayList<Item>`.

To fix this, create a new list at the start of your method, append to it in your `while` loop with `list.add()`, and `return list;` at the end of your method.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explication & code works perfectly but I just can mark one answer as correct, anyway, I recommend reading both answers (Cameron1024 and Federico Klez Culloca) in order to understand the problem and the solution, that is the same given by both.

Answer (score 1):

Because your method returns ArrayList you need to change your code.
Now in the first interation in the while loop you are returning the boolean value from the List.add() method. It's wrong.
In the while loop you should add an item to the list and outside the while you
should return the arrayList. 
Modify your code to:

```
 ArrayList<Item> loadItems() throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        File phaseOneFile = new File("Phase-1.txt");
        Scanner readPhaseOneFile = new Scanner(phaseOneFile);
        while (readPhaseOneFile.hasNextLine()){
            String actualLine = readPhaseOneFile.nextLine();
            String[] actualLineToItem = actualLine.split("=");
            Item newItem = new Item();
            newItem.itemName=actualLineToItem[0];
            newItem.itemWeight= Integer.parseInt(actualLineToItem[1]);
            itemList.add(newItem);
        } 
         return itemList;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code works but I find more helpful in order to support future problems the explanation that Federico Klez Colloca has given.